# The Christoffel symbol of a maximally symmetric space

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, symmetry, curvature

What is the form of the Christoffel symbol associated with the curvature tensor of a maximally symmetric space given by $$R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}=\frac{R}{d(d-1)}\left(g_{\mu\alpha}g_{\nu\beta}-g_{\mu\beta}g_{\nu\alpha}\right)~?$$

Comment: The Christofell symbols depend on the metric, so unless you fix a coordinate system you can't do better than the usual formula in terms of $g_{\mu\nu}$. Just being a maximally symmetric space doesn't give $g_{\mu\nu}$ any special properties.

Answer (score 2):

For completion I calculated the Christoffel symbols from Baptiste Bermond's answer using Mathematica.

$$\left.
\begin{array}{cc}
 \Gamma ^t{}_{r,r} & \frac{a(t) a'(t)}{1-k r^2} \\
 \Gamma ^t{}_{\theta ,\theta } & r^2 a(t) a'(t) \\
 \Gamma ^t{}_{\phi ,\phi } & r^2 a(t) \sin ^2(\theta ) a'(t) \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{t,r} & \frac{a'(t)}{a(t)} \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{r,r} & \frac{k r}{1-k r^2} \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{\theta ,\theta } & r \left(k r^2-1\right) \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{\phi ,\phi } & r \sin ^2(\theta ) \left(k r^2-1\right) \\
 \Gamma ^{\theta }{}_{t,\theta } & \frac{a'(t)}{a(t)} \\
 \Gamma ^{\theta }{}_{r,\theta } & \frac{1}{r} \\
 \Gamma ^{\theta }{}_{\phi ,\phi } & \sin (\theta ) (-\cos (\theta )) \\
 \Gamma ^{\phi }{}_{t,\phi } & \frac{a'(t)}{a(t)} \\
 \Gamma ^{\phi }{}_{r,\phi } & \frac{1}{r} \\
 \Gamma ^{\phi }{}_{\theta ,\phi } & \cot (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

They seem to agree with [this website](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll8.html). To calculate these symbols I used the [this](https://github.com/bram98/Calculate-the-Riemann-tensor.git) Mathematica notebook

---

EDIT: I uploaded this without much thought but after looking some more into it this answer isn't entirely correct. The Robertson-Walker metric has two parts: a time part and a maximally symmetric space part.
$$ ds^2=-dt^2+a^2(t)\gamma_{ij}(u)du_idu_j$$
Here $\gamma_{ij}$ is the maximally symmetric metric for the space part. In this case it is given by
$$ds^2=\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2\left(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2\right)$$
For this part you can check that it obeys $R_{ijkl}=k(g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk})$. The Christoffel symbols are calculated to be 
$$\left.
\begin{array}{cc}
 \Gamma ^r{}_{r,r} & \frac{k r}{1-k r^2} \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{\theta ,\theta } & r \left(k r^2-1\right) \\
 \Gamma ^r{}_{\phi ,\phi } & r \sin ^2(\theta ) \left(k r^2-1\right) \\
 \Gamma ^{\theta }{}_{r,\theta } & \frac{1}{r} \\
 \Gamma ^{\theta }{}_{\phi ,\phi } & \sin (\theta ) (-\cos (\theta )) \\
 \Gamma ^{\phi }{}_{r,\phi } & \frac{1}{r} \\
 \Gamma ^{\phi }{}_{\theta ,\phi } & \cot (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

In response to your comment: how can the Riemann tensor be a function of the metric itself? Well for the maximally symmetric metric you can calculate the Riemann tensor in two ways. The first way is by calculating the Christoffel symbols and from that construct the Riemann tensor (the painful way). The second way is by using the simple definition, i.e. $R_{ijkl}=k(g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk})$. It turns out that the expression you get from the painful way simplifies to the simple definition.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a little bit confused: In the general case the curvature tensor is supposed to be constructed out of the first and second order derivatives of the metric. But in the maximally symmetric case it is claimed to be a function of the metric itself, not of its derivatives. How can this be?

Comment: @user1999: it's a special case.  It's saying that the metric must satisfy a particular set of differential equations to be maximially symmetric.  Asking that question is like asking how it is possible to have an f such that ${\ddot f} = C^{2}f$

Comment: Thanks for the Edit part. As far as I understand the whole 4-dim RW metric is that of a maximally symmetric space (de-Sitter). However, it appears that the time components do not fit into this scheme, namely that the curvature in these components aren't a function of the metric (rather they are functions of its derivatives), isn't it?

Comment: @user1999 If I understand correctly only the spatial part $\gamma_{ij}du_idu_j$ is maximally symmetric. The Robertson Walker as a whole is not maximally symmetric (I believe). If someone could confirm this that would be nice

Comment: Take a look here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space In particular the slicing in here: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space#dS_slicing –

Answer (score 1):

Following the paper by Douglas H Laurence, http://www.blazartheory.com/files/notes/grnotes/Maximally_Symmetric_Spaces.pdf ,maximally symmetric spaces correspond (up to coordinates transformation) to the Robertson Walker metric, i.e.

$$ds^2=dt^2-a(t)^2\left(\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2d\Omega^2\right)$$

with $k$ the curvature value which can be equal to -1(hyperbolic geometry), 0(flat geometry), or +1 spheric geometry.

For the christoffel, since these are not tensors, it seems difficult to express them as easily.

Comment: Aren't robertson-walker spacetimes $T \times S$, where $S$ is a maximially symmetric 3-space, rather than being maximally symmetric 4-spaces?

Comment: Given the paper linked I do not think so but would have to check

Comment: the linked paper doesn't derive the Robertson walker metric or even reference it.

Comment: And take $k=1$.  In addition to the three rotations and three translations, (3)(4)/2 = 6 what are the additional Killing symmetries?  you need 4(5)/2 = 10 total of them, so four more.  The conformal Killing vector gives you one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But - as I asked AccidentalTaylorExpansion below - how is it possible that the curvature is proportional to the metric tensor itself and not to its derivatives? I am familiar with the Kiilling vectors arguments but cannot reconciliate it with the basic structure of the curvature tensor which is known to depend on the *derivatives* of the Christoffel symbol which, in turn, depends on the derivatives of the metric tensor.